# Deleting last line of bashrc file on all nodes of cluster

Tags: awk, ssh, sed

I have a cluster of `24 nodes`. I want to delete last line of `bashrc` file on all nodes

This is what I tried:

```
for (( i=1; i<25; i++ ))    
do    
  ssh node$i "sed -i '$d' ~/.bashrc"    
done
```

I also tried following variants

```
for (( i=1; i<25; i++ ))    
do    
  ssh node$i    
  sed -i '$d' ~/.bashrc    
  exit    
done
```

AND

```
for (( i=1; i<25; i++ ))    
do    
  ssh node$i 'sed -i '$d' ~/.bashrc'    
done
```

but the `$d` of the `sed` command is not correctly interpreted by the shell.
instead the local `bashrc` file is getting updated.
What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: `echo "sed -i '$d' ~/.bashrc" | ssh ssh node$i`

Comment: not directly for your reply but don't you need to add a little security by not deleting last line without checking a bit on it ? imagine you run twice the batch because you think it failed at first run ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for (( i=1; i<25; i++ ))    
do    
  ssh node$i "sed -i '\$d' ~/.bashrc"    
done
```

You need to escape `$`. Also hope that your `node$i` is correct!